# How to stop LinkedIn from sending repeated invitations to my contacts

Tags: linkedin

I accidentally "asked" LinkedIn to send invites to my contacts.
Now it's sending them repeated, multiple invites.

How do I disable this?

Everything I found was for an older UI of Linkedin and the instructions to jib with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a Google account which is associated to LinkedIn, and LinkedIn has access of your account and it keep sending invitation to your contacts automatically without your consent.

You need to remove the access given to LinkedIn to get rid of this issue.

- Login to your [Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
- Click on [Sign-in & security](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
- Click on [Apps with account access](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)

Now this will list all the Apps which have access of you Google account, click on the app and Remove Access for the app.

Never give permission to LinkedIn to access your contacts or never sync your phone or email contacts with LinkedIn.